# Check if variable challenge is in a list of valid values

Tags: python, list, validation, while-loop

I am on Windows 11 home, Python 3.12.2.  I am playing with the rock, paper scissors application.  I would like to check if the user input is a valid choice.  I experimented with try / except and if / in.  I would like to restart the loop if the user enters a value other than the valid entries.  I've commented out the current attempt.  Otherwise the program works OK.  Suggestions?

```
import random
valid_values = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "quit"]

victories = [
    ["paper", "rock"],
    ["rock", "scissors"],
    ["scissors", "paper"]
    ]

# create while loop until user exits
while True:
    # prompt user to challenge computer to a game
    user_input = input("Choose rock, paper, scissors, or quit ")
    challenge = user_input.lower()
    # check if user_input is valid
    # if challenge in valid_values:
    #    continue
    # else:
    #    print("this is not a valid value")
    if challenge == "quit":
        print("OK, bye")
        break
    else:
        # generate random rock, paper, scissors
        guess = random.choice(valid_values[0:2])
        # determine winner and display result
        if challenge == guess:
            print("Tie!")
        elif [challenge, guess] in victories:
            print(f"The {challenge} beats the {guess}, you win!")
        else:
            print(f"The {guess} beats the {challenge}, you lose!")type here
```

I would like to restart the loop if the entry is invalid.  I either get both the not valid and win/loss or i can't quit.  Maybe because of the continue

Answer (score 1):

Here is a change with a nested while loop:

```
import random
valid_values = ("rock", "paper", "scissors", "quit")
# stats are win. lose, draw
stats = [0,0,0]
victories = [
    ["paper", "rock"],
    ["rock", "scissors"],
    ["scissors", "paper"]
    ]
running = True

while running:
    challenge = None
    # generate random rock, paper, scissors
    guess = random.choice(valid_values[0:2])
    # prompt user to challenge computer to a valid game
    while challenge not in valid_values:
        challenge = input("Choose rock, paper, scissors, or quit: ").lower()
    if challenge == "quit":
        print("OK, bye")
        running = False
    else:
        # determine winner and display result
        if challenge == guess:
            stats[2] += 1
            print("Tie! Try again")
        elif [challenge, guess] in victories:
            stats[0] += 1
            print(f"The {challenge} beats the {guess}, you win!")
        else:
            stats[1] += 1
            print(f"The {guess} beats the {challenge}, you lose!")

    print(f"{stats[0]} wins, and {stats[1]} losses and {stats[2]} ties,")`
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you commented out is close but has the logics opposite, as it should `continue` the loop only if the input is *not* a valid value:

```
if challenge not in valid_values:
    print("this is not a valid value")
    continue
```

Comment: OK, I watched a few more videos.  Nested while loop is the answer.